# Meteor set android local file path for cordova plugin

Tags: cordova, meteor, cordova-plugins, filepath

How to set `file://` or `res://` path to file for cordova plugin in Meteor?

I need to set file path in **cordova-plugin-local-notifications**

```
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
    title: 'The Big Meeting',
    text: '4:15 - 5:15 PM\nBig Conference Room',
    smallIcon: 'res://some_icon.png',
    sound: 'file://android_asset/www/application/app/sound/some_file.mp3'
});
```

I noticed that cordova is building files into the directory **.meteor/local/cordova-build/www/application/app**, but cordova plugin not read files from android local directory. This plugin require that schema for this properties.

Comment: It's more likely to something like `file://sound/some_file.mp3` because it is relative to the base of the app, a bit like the way /public works for web assets

Comment: I tried to place the file in the main project directory or the public directory, but without any success. For some resason, meteor doesn't read these paths

Comment: You might need to grant permission for file access with a rule in mobile.settings: `App.accessRule('file:*');`

Comment: i set this `App.accessRule("*");`, so i think all should work, but not.

Comment: It won't work like that, you can't just set a wild card for everything

Comment: ok, I'll test it later and write if it helped

Comment: In my opinion it does not work. App.addResourceFile() works with `icon: 'res://icon.png'` but `file://`with different paths doesn't show image. it works strangely